# How to open reply box under parent comments using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, comments

I am implementing comments system in php, jquery. I am listing comments I need to open reply form or box under parent comment. My code is below

HTML COde are

```
<div id="record-1" class="friends_area">
    <a href="javascript:;">
        <img width="40" height="40" border="0" alt="" style="float:left; padding-right:9px;" src="">
    </a>
    <label class="name" style="float:left; width:390px;">
        <span>
            <span style="padding-left:10px;"> 59 minutes ago </span>
            <br clear="all">
            <div class="name" style="text-align:justify;float:left;">
                <em> Dsffdfdfd</em>
                <br clear="all">
                <div style="height:10px;">
                    <a id="post_id1" class="showCommentBox" href="javascript: void(0)">Reply</a>
                    -
                    <span id="like-panel"> </span>
                </div>
            </div>
    </label>
    <a class="delete_p" href="#" style="color:#ff0000;"> Image </a>
    <br clear="all">
    <div id="CommentPosted1">
        <div id="loadComments1" style="display:none"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="commentBox-1" class="commentBox" align="right" style="display:none"> </div>
</div>
<div id="record-1" class="friends_area">
    <a href="javascript:;">
        <img width="40" height="40" border="0" alt="" style="float:left; padding-right:9px;" src="">
    </a>
    <label class="name" style="float:left; width:390px;">
        <span>
            <span style="padding-left:20px;"> 59 minutes ago </span>
            <br clear="all">
            <div class="name" style="text-align:justify;float:left;">
                <em> Dsffdfdfd</em>
                <br clear="all">
                <div style="height:20px;">
                    <a id="post_id2" class="showCommentBox" href="javascript: void(0)">Reply</a>
                    -
                    <span id="like-panel"> </span>
                </div>
            </div>
    </label>
    <a class="delete_p" href="#" style="color:#ff0000;"> Image </a>
    <br clear="all">
    <div id="CommentPosted2">
        <div id="loadComments2" style="display:none"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="commentBox-2" class="commentBox" align="right" style="display:none"> </div>
</div>
   My Reply Box 
<div id="replymsgbox" style="display: none;">
    <form id="frmComment" novalidate="novalidate" method="POST" name="frmComment">
        <div>
            <textarea id="comment_text" class="" name="comment[text]"></textarea>
            <div id="error_text"> </div>
        </div>
        <div>           
            <input type="hidden" value="0" name="Parent_id" id=""Parent_id>             
            <input type="submit" value="Post" name="Submit">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

My Jquery :

```
//showCommentBox
$('a.showCommentBox').livequery("click", function(e){

var getpID = $(this).attr('id').replace('post_id','');

$('#replymsgbox', $(this).parents().next()).slideToggle('fast')

});
```

Any assistance appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify a selector in `.parents()` or else it won't return anything.
Or you could simply use `.parent()` if you want to access the direct parent of the element.

Documentation is [here](http://api.jquery.com/parents/)

Also, since you're using `.livequery`, I'm assuming it's because you're using [the plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery) and didn't want to use the default `.click()` or `.live()` methods.